# Change the ID of an element via jQuery and have selectors use the new ID

Tags: jquery

So I have element blocks being added dynamically (`<div><img><div><p></p></div></div>`) and once they load, I change the ID of them ($("#"+id).attr("id", new_id);)  I'm having an issue selecting that new ID though.  Selecting the old ID still works and applies to that element.  How do I make it recognize the new ID?

Site is at www.steamcompare.com.  You can test by adding a steam account.  While it's loading, I display an image with a transparent overlay.  Once it finishes, I fadeout the overlay, change the ID, and add a bunch of information to the overlay.  When you hover over it again, you'll see the extra info.  Now, if I fadeout the overlay with

```
$("#"+id).find('div.caption').fadeOut(200);
```

before I change the ID, it's fine.  If I move it past, it won't fadeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did resolve this, ended up having to rewrite how I was handling the elements.  Solved it by destroying the original one and creating a new one in it's place with the new ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#"+id).live('yourevent', function(){
    $("#"+id).find('div.caption').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: Who ever downvoted this, can you explain why?  Upon reading the documentation for it, it looks like it's exactly what I need.  Why downvote?  The only issue I can see is the event.  Not sure what event I could actually use to call it.

Comment: Ok, actually, after reading the documentation, this won't work.  "`In jQuery 1.3.x only the following JavaScript events (in addition to custom events) could be bound with .live(): click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup.   As of jQuery 1.4 the .live() method supports custom events as well as all JavaScript events that bubble.`"  I'm not using any of those events.

Comment: which event do you use? You didn't specify that in your question

Comment: The code is triggered upon a success callback via $.ajax.  If you view the code, the part in question is on line 102.

Comment: In your case I see it on $("#addUserForm").bind("submit")
    event, so change bind to live and it will work ;)

Comment: It's generated and assigned within the bind.  It doesn't even exist until the submit is made (line 48).  That's the original ID, the one that I can work with.  The one I change it to is farther down in an ajax call (line 102).

Comment: I see nothing on line 102. I see // TODO: Add a small button on the image overlay that controls removal, that way overlay links work on line 101

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was referencing lines in my editor.  :P  Line 130 is the one I'm talking about.

Comment: @AndrewBurgess: I have         pnotify_title : error_title, on line 130 ;)

Comment: @AndrewBurgess let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1716/discussion-between-genesis-and-andrew-burgess)